# Web api routing only permits one controller

Tags: web, asp.net-web-api

I created a new Web API project and created the following routing spec (actually I have simplified, looking for the bug):

```
  // Web API configuration and services
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
   );
```

When I make a call via ajax with the route:

```
 /api/account/GetSUID/0
```

everything works fine. When I just use a different controller:

```
 /api/tile/GetTileSet/0
```

it returns a status of 200 but instead of hitting my controller, it just returns *the contents of the default page in jqXHR.responseText*! It is as if it is just skipping any API routing like I am requesting the default site page.

I am baffled by this one as I have written literally hundreds of web API functions over the past few years in several other projects. I have never had any issue making calls to multiple controllers. I have looked high and low for what could be happening here and am hoping that someone here might have an idea.

Here is a sample method on the controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckRequestedID(int id, [FromUri]string Search)
    {
        if (!BSDIUtil.HasAllAcceptableCharacters(Search))
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        if (FolderModel.IDAlreadyExists(DAL, Search))  // We can check this because this function is only called when staff members are creating accounts for other people (participants always use their email).
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, false);
        else
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
    }
```

This will work if on the account controller but not on the tile controller.

One other thing, I am using the "Community" edition of Visual Studio and Windows 8.1

Comment: Maybe your browser cached the response... you can try to set `cache: false` option if you using jquery to send the AJAX request.

Comment: Can you share the definitions of your action methods (including any attributes)? I assume you have verified that the request is actually going to the correct URL (i.e. this isn't a client-side issue)?

Comment: nemesv - when I switch the controller to "account" the call succeeds so it can't be a caching issue. Ant - will do.  The calls are all relative and if I change the default document, the new default is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem that is likely to occur often but I have solved it and figured I would post it here in case anyone else has the same issue.

I am using web api in the context of a standard web forms app (although I am only using webforms for my reporting pages). In the web.config for a web forms app, you can declare the paths that the user has access to before authenticating. I was only providing access to the account controller: all others were not permitted due to my authentication mechanism. Once I authenticate (e.g. the forms authentication call) or if I change the location path to include only "api", the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem but in different context. Had many controllers and respective routing templates. Only one controller was responding to requests.
Later i realized my other controller classes were not **public**!!